# How to automate tasks in OSX/Windows and Android

Tags: android, python, macos, bash, shell

Hey guys sorry noob here,
I have been trying to be more productive recently and I have been trying to search the web for ways to automate tasks on my mac, windows and android machines. So far I have been forced to believe that on a  :
Mac : AppleScript can be used to write scripts (shell scrpits?) on a mac to automate tasks in the terminal like setting up and environment to compile certain code. Using the automator to launch shell scripts 
Windows : Writing scripts in python to automate tasks.
Android : Same as windows. Using "Tasker" to run this code as an app.

My main doubts are :
1) Do shell script run on windows?
2) If not what sort of scripts run on windows?
3) Can python be used to write shell scripts?
4) Can applScript be used to write shell scripts?
5) Can javaScripts be used to write shell scripts?
6) Can shell scripts actually be used to perform the intended tasks(lol noob strikes).
7) What are bash scripts and how are they different from shell scripts?
8) Can bash scripts be used on OSX and windows to perform intended tasks?
9) Where do I learn to create scripts?

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguous tasks. I need to set up a visual studio environment and cd into the required folder every time I want to compile the code. I wanted to automate that if possible. How do I achieve something like that?

Comment: for example  The first command I need to type is 1] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat                      followed by 2] cd C:\my7zip\CPP\7zip\   3] nmake NEW_COMPILER=1 MY_STATIC_LINK=1                                                                                            How do I write a script in windows to execute this three steps.

Comment: You should post a different question, state which visual studio, and what you have tried so far.   However, just put those commands into a `.bat` file and run it.  You can create a new `.bat` file using something as simple as Wordpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get some terms defined.  Unfortunately the words "shell" and "script" are vague, and of course I have no idea where you got these from.

A shell is any program that can run another.  So Windows Explorer is a shell, as is bash which runs on flavours of UNIX/Linux/OS X.  However, most people would include the ability to run as a Command Line Interpreter (CLI), like `cmd.exe` on Windows and bash on UNIXs.

A script is a program which will run from a text file without a separate compilation phase.  The compiler converts source code to machine readable format.  With scripting languages the compiler is built-in and usually invisible to the user.

Shells often have two features, a CLI and a language.  These two sometimes conflict, and speaking generally, languages that don't have the CLI component (Perl, Python, Ruby) are better at writing large and complex programs.  Shells are fine for relatively simple stuff.

**1) Do shell script run on windows?**
It depends on what you mean by a "shell script", but yes.  There are two command-line interpreters out-of-the-box on Windows, `cmd.exe` and `Powershell`.  Neither are compatible with other operating systems.

**2) If not what sort of scripts run on windows?** 
Now you  say "script" instead of "shell script".  Python, Perl, Ruby, all run on Windows happily, but you have to install them.

**3) Can python be used to write shell scripts?** 
**4) Can applScript be used to write shell scripts?** 
Yes - but why are you using he word "shell"

**5) Can javaScripts be used to write shell scripts?**
In theory, yes, but it is not designed for that, and not the best tool.

**6) Can shell scripts actually be used to perform the intended tasks(lol noob strikes).**
Come on!  What are the intended tasks?  Don't try to write an application in a shell script.  However, languages like Perl, Python, Ruby are a different matter, but no one would call those shells (although strictly speaking they can be).

**7) What are bash scripts and how are they different from shell scripts?**
Bash scripts are programs that use the bash (Bourne-Again shell) program.  These are shell scripts.  There are several flavours of shell, bash is probably the most popular.

**8) Can bash scripts be used on OSX and windows to perform intended tasks?**
Bash runs under Cygwin on Windows, a kind of emulation environment.  Bash on OS X is native.  I don't know what your intended tasks are, so this is impossible to say.

**9) Where do I learn to create scripts?**
Anything you type on a command-line can go into a **shell** script, which is just a text file created with an editor.

Languages like Python, Perl, and Ruby all have extensive documentation and tutorials.